# Session attributes loss after send another request

Tags: php, symfony, session, session-cookies

I have problem with session attributes, it is set but lost after another request.

- `Symfony 2.4.10`, `PHP 5.4.17`, `fedora 17`
- Session store using `PDOSessionHandler`
- I want to share my session between two domain `www.mydomain.com` and `clone.mydomin.com`
- I have set `php_value session.cookie_domain .mydomain.com` in virtualhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my answer, that I was making two ajax request concurrent, first was not able to set session data another and I didn't want to set any session data in second ajax request so I had used `session_write_close()` in begging of that.